# How to call a function in page load asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> The function below is found in a class called page.cs

```
public static List<string> MyFunction()
        {
         var retList = new List<string>();
        
        retList.Add("xzy");
        retList.Add("abc");
        
return retList;
        }
```

> On page load how to call the function and check if the list contains
> xzy and abc?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call MyFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really show enough code for us to see your problem.  As I read it, you have a class `Page` in a file named `page.cs` and it looks like this in part:

```
public class Page {
    public static List<string> MyFunction()
    {
        var retList = new List<string>
        {
            "xyz",
            "abc",
        };
        return retList;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = MyFunction();
    }
}
```

*(Note that I've simplified your initialization of the list - my code is equivalent to yours)*

The code I show compiles.  Assuming that `MyFunction` and `Page_Load` are in the same class, then you can directly call `MyFunction` from `Page_Load` (static functions can be called from instance function (within the same class)).

If they are not in the same class, let's say that `MyFunction` was a static function in another class (say `OtherClass`).  Then `Page_Load` could call it in the way @joelcoehoorn describes:

```
OtherClass.MyFunction();
```

The reverse is not true.  A static function cannot directly call an instance function (one without the `static` keyword) in the same class.  You'll get an error complaining that you need an instance.  For example, if `MyFunction` wanted to call `Page_Load`, it would need to do something like this:

```
var page = new Page();
//possibly do something with page
page.PageLoad(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);
//possibly do more stuff with page
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you need to add more to your question.  In particular:

1. Show the class declarations around your method definitions.  It's not clear (but it is important) which class(es) have which methods
2. Show us the code you have and any error messages you get (compile time and runtime)

Also note that I don't believe you should be getting `Non-invocable member 'page' cannot be used like a method.` if you did what @joelcoehoorn describes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the function using the type name. However, a file named `page.cs` likely had a class named `Page`, which will conflict with the base ASP.Net Page class. Therefore you must either fully-qualify the name (`MyNamespace.Page.MyFunction()`) or change the name of the class.

Comment: Not working: it says Non-invocable member 'page' cannot be used like a method.